# What is the word for talking to someone when youre sad or worried

Tags: meaning

Im feeling a little bit emotional and i just want to talk to someone about it, i dont need any solutions i just want to let it out.. What is the right word that means all of this

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of words you could use. **Venting** could signify that you are speaking an unadulterated stream of thoughts, but venting often has a negative connotation to owing to the fact that is often used to mean a one-side conversation that doesn't necessarily have a goal of soliciting feedback from the second party. (I personally feel that is is probably closest to what you would use given your scenario.) You could use **confessing** if you feel particularly ashamed of what is bothering you. The Roman Catholic church (and perhaps others) use confession as part of the process of absolving sins (this word also may have some negative connotations). There are several colloquial terms: **uncorking**, **letting loose**, **sounding off** (this is often used more toward exposing another entity), **coming clean** (not dissimilar to confessing).